# Atualizar saldo com receita e despesa

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Tenho uma aplicação, onde existe uma opção para cadastrar uma CONTA com saldo inicial igual a zero e duas opções para cadastrar RECEITAS e DESPESAS.

Sendo que, quando cadastro uma RECEITA, o saldo da conta atualiza de acordo com o valor cadastrado na receita.

Caso seja cadastrado uma DESPESA, é subtraído o mesmo valor do saldo da conta

> Cenário:
>   RECEITA = 80,00
>   SALDO DA CONTA = 80,00
>
> DESPESA = 30,00
>   SALDO DA CONTA = 50,00

Até aqui, tudo bem.(funcionando corretamente) O problema é que não sei como fazer para atualizar o SALDO quando editar ou excluir uma RECEITA ou DESPESA.

Exemplo:
Quando editar o valor de uma RECEITA quero que o saldo seja atualizado.
Quando editar o valor de uma DESPESA quero que o saldo seja atualizado.
Quando excluir uma DESPESA quero que o valor da DESPESA, some ao saldo.
Quando excluir uma RECEITA quero que o valor da RECEITA, subtraia ao saldo.

Podem me ajudar com esta função e query?

A tabela onde são cadastradas a RECEITA e DESPESA tem as seguintes colunas:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lancamentos` (
  `idLancamentos` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `descricao` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `data_vencimento` DATE NOT NULL,
  `categoria_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `conta_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_pagamento` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `baixado` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `cliente_fornecedor` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `forma_pgto` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `anexo` VARCHAR(250) NULL,
  `clientes_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idLancamentos`),
  INDEX `fk_lancamentos_clientes1` (`clientes_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_lancamentos_clientes1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`clientes_id`)
    REFERENCES `clientes` (`idClientes`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;
```

A tabela onde são cadastradas as categorias tem as seguintes colunas:

```
//1 para RECEITA
//0 para DESPESA

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categorias` (
  `idCategoria` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome_categoria` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `tipo_categoria` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `status_categoria` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `data_cadastro_categoria` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCategoria`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;
```

A tabela onde são cadastradas as contas e saldos tem as seguintes colunas:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'contas' (
  'idConta' INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'conta' VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  'banco' VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  'numero' VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  'saldo' DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  'status' TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  'data_cadastro' DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (idConta))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;
```

Para adicionar DESPESA, estou usando a funçaõ:

```
function adicionarDespesa() {

    if(!$this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'aLancamento')){
       $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Você não tem permissão para adicionar lançamentos.');
       redirect(base_url());
    }

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->data['custom_error'] = '';
    $urlAtual = $this->input->post('urlAtual');
    if ($this->form_validation->run('despesa') == false) {
        $this->data['custom_error'] = (validation_errors() ? '<div class="form_error">' . validation_errors() . '</div>' : false);
    } else {

        $vencimento = $this->input->post('vencimento');
        $pagamento = $this->input->post('pagamento');
        $valor = $this->input->post('valor');
        $conta = $this->input->post('conta_id');

        if($pagamento != null){
            $pagamento = explode('/', $pagamento);
            $pagamento = $pagamento[2].'-'.$pagamento[1].'-'.$pagamento[0];
        }

        if($vencimento == null){
            $vencimento = date('d/m/Y');
        }

        try {

            $vencimento = explode('/', $vencimento);
            $vencimento = $vencimento[2].'-'.$vencimento[1].'-'.$vencimento[0];

        } catch (Exception $e) {
           $vencimento = date('Y/m/d'); 
        }

        $data = array(
            'descricao' => set_value('descricao'),
            //'valor' => set_value('valor'),
            'valor' => $valor,
            'data_vencimento' => $vencimento,
            'categoria_id' => $this->input->post('categoria_id'),
            'conta_id'=> $conta,
            //'conta_id' => $this->input->post('conta_id'),
            'baixado' => $this->input->post('pago'),
            'data_pagamento' => $pagamento != null ? $pagamento : date('Y-m-d'),
            'baixado' => $this->input->post('pago'),
            'cliente_fornecedor' => set_value('fornecedor'),
            'forma_pgto' => $this->input->post('formaPgto'),
            'tipo' => set_value('tipo')
        );

        if ($this->financeiro_model->add('lancamentos',$data) == TRUE) {

            $sql = "UPDATE contas set saldo = saldo - ? WHERE idConta = ?";
            $this->db->query($sql, array($valor, $conta));
            echo json_encode(array('result'=> true));

            $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Despesa adicionada com sucesso!');
            redirect($urlAtual);
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Ocorreu um erro ao tentar adicionar despesa!');
            echo json_encode(array('result'=> false));
            redirect($urlAtual);
        }
    }

    $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Ocorreu um erro ao tentar adicionar despesa.');
    redirect($urlAtual);


}
```

Para adicionar RECEITA, estou usando a funçaõ:

```
    function adicionarReceita() {

    if(!$this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'aLancamento')){
       $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Você não tem permissão para adicionar lançamentos.');
       redirect(base_url());
    }

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->data['custom_error'] = '';
    $urlAtual = $this->input->post('urlAtual');

    if ($this->form_validation->run('receita') == false) {
        $this->data['custom_error'] = (validation_errors() ? '<div class="form_error">' . validation_errors() . '</div>' : false);
    } else {


        $valor = $this->input->post('valor');
        $vencimento = $this->input->post('vencimento');
        $recebimento = $this->input->post('recebimento');
        $conta = $this->input->post('conta_id');

        if($recebimento != null){
            $recebimento = explode('/', $recebimento);
            $recebimento = $recebimento[2].'-'.$recebimento[1].'-'.$recebimento[0];
        }

        if($vencimento == null){
            $vencimento = date('d/m/Y');
        }

        try {

            $vencimento = explode('/', $vencimento);
            $vencimento = $vencimento[2].'-'.$vencimento[1].'-'.$vencimento[0];   

        } catch (Exception $e) {
           $vencimento = date('Y/m/d'); 
        }

        $data = array(
            'descricao' => set_value('descricao'),
            //'valor' => set_value('valor'),
            'valor' => $valor,
            'data_vencimento' => $vencimento,
            'data_pagamento' => $recebimento != null ? $recebimento : date('Y-m-d'),
            'categoria_id' => $this->input->post('categoria_id'),
            'conta_id'=> $conta,
            //'conta_id' => $this->input->post('conta_id'),
            'baixado' => $this->input->post('recebido'),
            'cliente_fornecedor' => set_value('cliente'),
            'forma_pgto' => $this->input->post('formaPgto'),
            'tipo' => set_value('tipo')
        );

        if ($this->financeiro_model->add('lancamentos',$data) == TRUE) {

            $sql = "UPDATE contas set saldo = saldo + ? WHERE idConta = ?";
            $this->db->query($sql, array($valor, $conta));
            echo json_encode(array('result'=> true));

            $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Receita adicionada com sucesso!');
            redirect($urlAtual);

        } else {
            $this->data['custom_error'] = '<div class="form_error"><p>Ocorreu um erro.</p></div>';

            echo json_encode(array('result'=> false));
        }
    }

    $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Ocorreu um erro ao tentar adicionar receita.');
    redirect($urlAtual);

}
```

Para editar RECEITA e DEPESA, estou usando a funçaõ:

```
    public function editar(){   
    if(!$this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'eLancamento')){
       $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Você não tem permissão para editar lançamentos.');
       redirect(base_url());
    }

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->data['custom_error'] = '';
    $urlAtual = $this->input->post('urlAtual');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('descricao', '', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('fornecedor', '', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('valor', '', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('vencimento', '', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pagamento', '', 'trim|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
        $this->data['custom_error'] = (validation_errors() ? '<div class="form_error">' . validation_errors() . '</div>' : false);
    } else {

        $vencimento = $this->input->post('vencimento');
        $pagamento = $this->input->post('pagamento');
        $valor = $this->input->post('valor');
        $conta = $this->input->post('conta_id');

        try {

            $vencimento = explode('/', $vencimento);
            $vencimento = $vencimento[2].'-'.$vencimento[1].'-'.$vencimento[0];

            $pagamento = explode('/', $pagamento);
            $pagamento = $pagamento[2].'-'.$pagamento[1].'-'.$pagamento[0];

        } catch (Exception $e) {
           $vencimento = date('Y/m/d'); 
        }

        $data = array(
            'descricao' => $this->input->post('descricao'),
            //'valor' => $this->input->post('valor'),
            'valor' => $valor,
            'categoria_id' => $this->input->post('categoria_id'),
            'conta_id'=> $conta,
            'data_vencimento' => $vencimento,
            'data_pagamento' => $pagamento,
            'baixado' => $this->input->post('pago'),
            'cliente_fornecedor' => $this->input->post('fornecedor'),
            'forma_pgto' => $this->input->post('formaPgto'),
            'tipo' => $this->input->post('tipo')
        );

        if ($this->financeiro_model->edit('lancamentos',$data,'idLancamentos',$this->input->post('id')) == TRUE) {


            $sql = "UPDATE contas set saldo = saldo - ? WHERE idConta = ?";
            $this->db->query($sql, array($valor, $conta));
            echo json_encode(array('result'=> true));

            $this->session->set_flashdata('success','lançamento editado com sucesso!');
            redirect($urlAtual);
        } else {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Ocorreu um erro ao tentar editar lançamento!');
            echo json_encode(array('result'=> false));
            redirect($urlAtual);
        }

        $sql = "UPDATE contas set saldo = saldo + ? WHERE idConta = ?";
            $this->db->query($sql, array($valor, $conta));
            echo json_encode(array('result'=> true));
    }

    $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Ocorreu um erro ao tentar editar lançamento.');
    echo json_encode(array('result'=> false));
    redirect($urlAtual);

    $data = array(
            'descricao' => $this->input->post('descricao'),
            //'valor' => $this->input->post('valor'),
            'valor' => $valor,
            'categoria_id' => $this->input->post('categoria_id'),
            'conta_id'=> $conta,
            'data_vencimento' => $this->input->post('vencimento'),
            'data_pagamento' => $this->input->post('pagamento'),
            'baixado' => $this->input->post('pago'),
            'cliente_fornecedor' => set_value('fornecedor'),
            'forma_pgto' => $this->input->post('formaPgto'),
            'tipo' => $this->input->post('tipo')
        );
    print_r($data);

}
```

Para excluir RECEITA e DEPESA, estou usando a funçaõ:

```
    public function excluirLancamento(){   

    if(!$this->permission->checkPermission($this->session->userdata('permissao'),'dLancamento')){
       $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Você não tem permissão para excluir lançamentos.');
       redirect(base_url());
    }

    $id = $this->input->post('id');

    if($id == null || ! is_numeric($id)){
        $json = array('result'=>  false);
        echo json_encode($json);
    }
    else{

        $result = $this->financeiro_model->delete('lancamentos','idLancamentos',$id); 
        if($result){
            $json = array('result'=>  true);
            echo json_encode($json);
        }
        else{
            $json = array('result'=>  false);
            echo json_encode($json);
        }

    }
}
```

MODEL FINANCEIRO

```
function get($table,$fields,$where='',$perpage=0,$start=0,$one=false,$array='array'){

    $this->db->select($fields);
    $this->db->from($table);
    $this->db->order_by('data_vencimento', 'asc');
    $this->db->limit($perpage,$start);
    if($where){
        $this->db->where($where);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get();

    $result =  !$one  ? $query->result() : $query->row();
    return $result;
}


function getById($id){
    $this->db->where('idClientes',$id);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    return $this->db->get('clientes')->row();
}

function add($table,$data){
    $this->db->insert($table, $data);         
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() == '1')
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;       
}

function edit($table,$data,$fieldID,$ID){
    $this->db->where($fieldID,$ID);
    $this->db->update($table, $data);

    if ($this->db->affected_rows() >= 0)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;       
}

function delete($table,$fieldID,$ID){
    $this->db->where($fieldID,$ID);
    $this->db->delete($table);
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() == '1')
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;        
}

function count($table, $where) {

    $this->db->from($table);
    if($where){
        $this->db->where($where);
    }
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
}
```

Comment: Em qual momento deseja atualizar o saldo? Nas sua tabela não tem o saldo da conta separada por lançamento. Já que assim você somente faz o calculo subtraindo a despesa da receita. Mais o correto e ter o saldo no momento do lançamento

Comment: Desejo atualizar o saldo quando editar ou excluir um lançamento.
Existe uma outra tabela(contas) que contem a coluna saldo.

Queria que todos os cálculos fossem feitos nesta tabela(contas).

Comment: @WillianCoqueiro Tem alguma sugestão de como posso fazer isto?
Seria criar uma coluna na tebela "lancamentos", calculando o saldo no momento do lançamento?

Comment: É o correto. No momento do lançamento ele calcular o saldo no momento calculando o saldo junto com o lançamento e salvar no banco.

Comment: Até assim você pode buscar o saldo no periodo.

Comment: @WillianCoqueiro Vou tentar fazer algo deste tipo, mas ainda não sei como ficará a query.
Sabe como fazer, baseado nos controlles acima?

Comment: Geralmente bancos fazem saldos diário. Ficaria melhor. Então toda vez que você atualizar algum lançamento, atualize o saldo diário e os saldos de dias posteriores. E para diferenciar receita de despesa, crie uma coluna tipo_lancamento com valores de D para despesa e C para crédito. É bastante coisa. Mais acredito ser a melhor maneira.

Comment: O saldo diário me refiro ao saldo do dia. Quando for feito a consulta ele faça o cálculo de todos os dias para achar o saldo da conta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste caso você pode trabalhar com TRIGGERS, que são gatilhos configurados em uma tabela, que executam uma query sempre que é inserido, atualizado ou excluído um registro.

Documentação: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Exemplo:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_lancamentos_ai AFTER INSERT ON lancamentos
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE contas SET
            saldo = (
              CASE NEW.tipo
                WHEN '1' THEN saldo + NEW.valor
                WHEN '0' THEN saldo - NEW.valor
                ELSE saldo
              END
            )
        WHERE
            (idConta = NEW.conta_id);
    END;

CREATE TRIGGER trg_lancamentos_au AFTER UPDATE ON lancamentos
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE contas SET
            saldo = (
              CASE NEW.tipo
                WHEN '1' THEN saldo - OLD.valor + NEW.valor
                WHEN '0' THEN saldo + OLD.valor - NEW.valor
                ELSE saldo
              END
            )
        WHERE
            (idConta = NEW.conta_id);
    END;

CREATE TRIGGER trg_lancamentos_ad AFTER DELETE ON lancamentos
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE contas SET
            saldo = (
              CASE OLD.tipo
                WHEN '1' THEN saldo - OLD.valor
                WHEN '0' THEN saldo + OLD.valor
                ELSE saldo
              END
            )
        WHERE
            (idConta = OLD.conta_id);
    END;
```

Fiddle com o exemplo em ação: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jL5RjoCtnM9yxz3eALTb3w/0

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de cadastrar a despesa com o valor 10, por exemplo, cadastre como -10. Além de poupar uma coluna do banco de dados, contribui para um melhor entendimento. Retorne a soma de tudo com o comando `SUM`, exemplo:

A coluna valor da tabela está populada com os seguintes valores:

**`150
-10
-30
180
-500`**

Com a querry: `SELECT SUM(valor) FROM tabela` é retornado o número da soma de todos os valores, o lucro(que neste caso é -210)

Comment: Como assim?
Não entendi o motivo de fazer um insert com valores negativos.

Esta query, já esta fazendo isso:

$sql = "UPDATE contas set saldo = saldo - ? WHERE idConta = ?";
$this->db->query($sql, array($valor, $conta));

A questão é editar e excluir um registro e o saldo ser atualizado automaticamente.